# storing images in file system with nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, file-upload

as the question implies I want to store images into the filesystem and save a link to it in the database.
but NHibernate doesn't save the file path in the database. here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Item item, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                string imageName = image.FileName;
                string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/ItemImages/") , imageName);
                image.SaveAs(location);
                item.Image= imageName;
            }

            menuItemRepository.SaveOrUpdate(item);
// here the debug show the image path has correctly assigned to the image property
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Image);
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", item.Name);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", item.Parent);
            }
            else
            {
                // there is something wrong with the data values 
                return View(Item);
            }
        }
```

but after repositor save or update the item, when I look at the database, the image is null. I tried to assign something ele like image name and it did work but the for image path is not working!! I'm confused why this happen. does anyone have any idea?

```
   public class Item
{
  public virtual string Image { get; set; } 
} 

public calss ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
  public ItemMap()
{
Map(x => x.Image).Length(100);
}
}
```

//////////Repository

```
 public T SaveOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: what is the code of menuItemRepository.SaveOrUpdate?

Comment: @MichaC code added. the repository can save or update all of my entities. also I can save images as binary files to the db, but I think saving it to the app directory be nice for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented a sessionPreRequest module for my MVC app. so I was doing commit() operation there.
I checked and saw my transaction is not committing and is rolling back. and checked the error and the image column in the database was `nvarchar(50)`, but the string which had the path of image was mor than 50 characters. so I changed to `nvarchar(200)` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess - the save is not being flushed to the database.  See the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing):

> From time to time the `ISession` will execute the SQL statements needed to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of objects held in memory. This process, *flush*, occurs by default at the following points
>
> - from some invocations of `Find()` or `Enumerable()`
> - from `NHibernate.ITransaction.Commit()`
> - from `ISession.Flush()`

I see nothing in your code that would trigger a flush.  Wrap your `SaveOrUpdate` in a transaction:

```
using (var trx = menuItemRepository.BeginTransaction())
{
    menuItemRepository.SaveOrUpdate(item);
    trx.Commit();
}
```

`trx.Commit()` will flush that pending `update` query to the database.